# Comparing one variable against two in php

Tags: php, variables

Is it possible to compare one variable with two others at the same time? Not in the sense that var1 is compared to var2 and then var1 is compared to var3. For example comparing a variable holding a full name to a variable holding a first name and a variable holding a second name:

```
    if ($string1 == "$string2 $string3")  {
    echo "some code";
} else  {
    echo "some other code";
}
```

I know the above code would produce an error but is this a possibility? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see no reason why the code would produce an error.  Could you elaborate on what is wrong with it?

Comment: Seems the code works just fine...?

Comment: No. either you compare the variable values individually (v1 = v2 -> v2 -> v3), or you don't compare them at all. "$string2 $string3" produces a NEW string with a NEW value . e.g. `1 == 1 && 1 == 2` vs. `1 == '12'` are fundamentally different comparisons.

Comment: @WesleyMurch It would seem that way except for this phrase: `Not in the sense that var1 is compared to var2 and then var1 is compared to var3.`

Comment: $string1 = "fullname" $string2 = "firstname" $string3 = "surname" if I wanted to check that the full name is the same as the first name plus the surname, how would I do this?

Comment: @user3298004 Exactly as you do in your code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say

```
$string1 = "FirstName LastName";
$string2 = "FirstName";
$string3 = "LastName";
```

then you need to do something like:

```
$full_string = $string2 . " " . $string3;
if ($string1 == $full_string)  {
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response but I am trying to compare the first variable with the sum of the second and third variables. for example imagine I need to compare a full name with a first name + second name to see if they match. is this possible?

Comment: check the revised answer then

Comment: That should be `$string1 = "FirstName LastName";` @zoranc - The way you have it now with a typo, there will be no match. You forgot the `r`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming the full name is structured like "First Last"

you can do:

```
if($full == $first.' '.$last)
```

which actually should work the same as your OP though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment,I think you  Probably you need to do this

concatinate `$string2`and `$string3`.Put that value into another variable..say`$result`.
Then compare `$string1` with `$result`

example:

`$result`=`$string2` `.` `$string3`;

`if ($string1 == "$result")  {
    echo "some code";`